# HasFlags always returns true for None (0) value in enum

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

This is the enum definition:

```
[Flags]
enum Animals
{
    None = 0,
    Dog = 1,
    Cat = 2,
    Horse = 4,
    Zebra = 8,
}
```

Now, given the following code, why does the HasFlag method return true for the value Animals.None?

```
Animals myAnimals = Animals.Dog | Animals.Horse;

var hasNone = myAnimals.HasFlag(Animals.None);    //true! Why?
var hasCat = myAnimals.HasFlag(Animals.Cat);      //false
var hasDog = myAnimals.HasFlag(Animals.Dog);      //true
var hasHorse = myAnimals.HasFlag(Animals.Horse);  //true
var hasZebra = myAnimals.HasFlag(Animals.Zebra);  //false
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`HasFlag` is effectively this:

```
HasFlag = (GivenFlag & Value) == GivenFlag;

//"Anything" AND 0 == 0  --> always true
```

Answer (score 11):

I've come up against this before myself.
It's by design in the .NET Framework:

> If the underlying value of flag is zero, the method returns true. If this behavior is not desirable, you can use the Equals method to test for equality with zero and call HasFlag only if the underlying value of flag is non-zero, as the following example illustrates.

You can read a little more about this [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag#remarks)

Comment: To expand on this, the solution I've implemented is to handle the Zero edgecase by calling `value.Equals(myEnum.Zero)`, then every other case is handled by `.HasFlag`.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a plethora of answers describing WHY this happens, so I will just add that what you can do to get what you're looking for is to not use `HasFlag` in that case, but instead do `var hasNone = myAnimals == Animals.None`.

I personally really loathe extension methods, but it would be possible to put this in an extension on `Enum` if you really value being able to just write `myOptionEnum.HasNoFlags()`. I would just run with explicitly checking for the `None` value in this special case though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing the 'None' element.  It is a 'magic value' and interferes with proper Flags Enum operations (like HasFlag()).

If there is no value then use Nullable i.e. Animals? (which now supports primitive types)

**EDIT**: I needed a 'Default' value (that is non-zero) for use in a serializable object in order to avoid using Nullable (which conflicted with the business logic).  But I think this is still better than using 'None=0'.

Comment: Zero is the default value for any enum, so it's better to keep it in the enum.

Comment: @VladislavBorovikov, having 'None=0' breaks HasFlag() logic. One can always test an enum for 0 just like testing an object for null. The approach I described is if you want HasFlag() to work every time.

Answer (score 0):

Well `Enum.HasFlags` resolves as something like the following:

```
var hasNone = (myAnimals & Animals.None) == Animals.None
```

This will always be true for a zero-value-enum-field.

Answer (score 0):

From **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx)**

The HasFlag method returns the result of the following Boolean expression.

```
thisInstance And flag = flag
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the defined behavior of the `HasFlag` method.  From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) documentation

> if the underlying value of flag is zero, the method returns true